# Cannot change dcom permission on Windows x64 2012 R2 datacenter

Tags: windows, dll, permissions, dcom

Cannot change dcom permission on Windows x64 2012 R2 datacenter. The component is 32 bits. I start the config running "mmc comexp /32". I can change it, but Windows  won't save the configuration. I check "customize" (the picture shows Windows in portuguese, so it's 'Personalizar') and save. When I come back to the security tab, it's again on "Default". I already went to regedit and gave all possible permissions on the component entry. Check image here: http://imgur.com/VVNVLMo

Another thing, I can't change the configuration of most components,
they are grayed out.

Any idea to fix this? Windows makes so unthinkable problems :z

Comment: This question is probably more adequate for serverfault.com
Stackoverflow is intended for programmer questions.

Comment: You cannot, probably an user with higher privilege can. I suggest you to create a new question there. If you do no get an answer here, you may delete the question in some days.